# Grunt autoprefixer error - Can't parse CSS: property missing value near line 12:21

Tags: css, less, gruntjs

When I run `grunt serve` or `grunt autoprefixer` a warning occurs but there is no mention to file path, just line and column.

```
$ grunt autoprefixer
Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
Warning: Can't parse CSS: property missing value near line 12:21 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-05-05 20:24:50 UTC)
loading tasks       3ms  ■■■■■■■■■■■ 13%
autoprefixer:dist  19ms  ■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■ 83%
Total 23ms
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `grunt autoprefixer --verbose` to run Grunt in verbose mode and have it spit out the file names and expanded options object